# elasticsearch glibc memory corruption

Tags: memory, java, corruption, elasticsearch

My elastic search clusters keep crashing for no reason.
All I can see in the logs is :

```
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2015/04/17 19:10:09 | *** glibc detected *** /usr/java/jre1.7.0_04/bin/java: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f6a2c4d8560 ***
```

I have a cluster with one master and two slaves.
I do have an old version ("0.20.2") but it has never been a problem so far... I can not update easily and will only consider it as a last resort.

I don't really know where to start; 
So far, I have changed the following setting:

- `wrapper.java.additional.3=-Xss256k` to `wrapper.java.additional.3=-Xss512k`
- and have deleted all the indices (this needed some cleaning)

Unfortunately, the problem is still happening even without any indices..

```
java is  java version "1.7.0_04" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Before the wrapper setting change I was also getting

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/04/17 16:03:05 | 7fffe41fe000-7fffe4200000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/04/17 16:03:05 | ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/04/17 16:03:05 | JVM process is gone.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/04/17 16:03:05 | JVM exited unexpectedly.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/04/17 16:03:10 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2015/04/17 16:03:10 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/04/17 16:03:39 | JVM received a signal UNKNOWN (6).
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/04/17 16:03:39 | JVM process is gone.
service.log
```

Happy to provide whatever else information is needed to help troubleshoot this.

Comment: You should at least update the JRE.

Comment: thanks updating the JRE and ES seem to have fix my issues.

Comment: for everyone who faces similar problems, its worth to note that we are on a parralels / openvz platform that suffers this problem: github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9582  .   Removing SIGAR was the solution (although its a temporary one)